# Anisble tower marks playbook using max_fail_percentage as failed

Tags: error-handling, ansible, ansible-tower

Does anyone have experience with using the Ansible playbook option: max_fail_percentage in Tower?

I'm currently using this option so my configure playbook can continue on, as long as no more than 50% of hosts fail. E.G with two hosts, if one passes and one fails the play will carry on despite that failure and will run all the way to completion. I have tested this functionality and it is working.

Unexpectedly, even when half of the hosts fail and the play runs all the way to the end, Ansible Tower marks the overall play as failed... This is a problem for me as i have notifications that are sent out when the play is completed based on overall success/failure status.

Is this expected behavior?
Does anyone know how I can change this behavior and have the play marked as successful?

[Play status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eBBf.png)

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************

HOST1                       : ok=25   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=2    skipped=8
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0
HOST2                       : ok=23   changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=8

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour, since one of your hosts failed. It is normal behaviour for the rest of the hosts to finish (`max_fail_percentage` lets you end the play early, it is not preventing the play from ending), and then Tower sees that some things failed so it marks the play as failed.

The only thing I'm aware of that actually clears errors is using `rescue`.
This might not work for Tower since the tasks are still technically failures, but it's worth a try.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - block:
        - assert:
            that:
              - inventory_hostname.startswith('s')
      rescue:
        - debug:
            msg: It's all good
```

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [assert] ******************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "inventory_hostname.startswith('s')",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "msg": "Assertion failed"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "It's all good"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=1    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply @flowerysong. I considered using a rescue, however I have a concern with that. If I use a rescue and 100% hosts failed instead of just 50% the rescue would do its thing and the play would continue? I'm trying to only continue on if 50% or less fail, and when that happens I'm hoping the play can be marked as successful. Your reply makes total sense however, and it sounds like this won't be possible as any failure will cause tower to mark the overall play as failed it seems.